# Session not carrying over multiple pages

Tags: php

checkPHP.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == "no") {
        echo "not logged in";
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == "yes") {
        echo "logged in";
    }
    else if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){
        echo "session not set";
    }
?>

<html>

<form id = "form2" method="post" action="checklogin2.php">
    Email:<br />
<input type="text" name="myusername" size = "35"/><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="text" name="mypassword" size = "35" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" /><br />
</form>

</html>
```

checklogin2.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "yes";
    header("location:checkPHP.php");
?>
```

The first time i load the page, the session is not set. But when I log in, it is suppose to set it to yes, then redirect the user back to the homepage. However both times it just says that the session is not set. So I guess i'm not sure how to set the session correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely a cookie issue. Have you established whether a cookie is set and sent? Using the network console of your browser (IE, Chrome, FF)

Comment: check `session_id()` in all those pages after you do session_start(). If the id's changing, your session cookie isn't set properly and gets lost between pages. producing a brand new "clean" session each time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that PHP doesn't get a chance to write the session info before the header redirect and script exit.  Try this:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "yes";
 session_write_close();
 header("location:checkPHP.php");  
 exit;
```

I like to add the explicit `exit` after all header redirects, just in case the script has time to do something else before the client receives the header and runs away...

I've also seen people do this to get around this situation:

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "yes";
  session_regenerate_id(true);
  header("location:checkPHP.php");
```

Comment: not possible. sessions that have been session_start()'d will be committed when the script exits. unless the script is killed with a fatal error, it doesn't matter if it's leaving via exit(), header redirect, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP to be able to set a session variable, it must be able to identify the client, right? Well, the default method used to accomplish this is via a cookie set when you initiate the session. Since it appears you are redirecting the user to the member's only page using the Location header on the same page the session is initiated, the PHPSESSID cookie will not be set. Thus, once the user arrives at the member's only page, PHP won't be able to identify the user. Their session variable is still there, but PHP won't give it to a stranger. :)

Basically, in your HTTP reponse that includes the Set-Cookie header, it needs to be a regular 200 OK response and not a protocol level redirection.
Hope that helps

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back up that cookies are not set on redirects?

Comment: @Jack The HTTP 1.0 standard per http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109 in section "4.3.5 Sending Cookies in Unverifiable Transactions" says that cookies should not be set from unverifiable transactions. It states specifically that "Unverifiable transactions typically arise when a user agent automatically requests inlined or embedded entities or when it resolves redirection (3xx) responses from an origin server." So, "Set-Cookie" is not to be acted upon by browsers / user agents for 3xx redirects. Nothing in HTTP 1.1 changes this part of HTTP.

Comment: Pretty much, he's *creating* the session cookie on the same page as the redirect. If he creates the session on another page beforehand (therefore creating the cookie beforehand) this won' be an issue.

Comment: But the cookie is set when the login form is shown, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Jack Doh. I should have looked at his code more carefully. That'll teach me for skimming. Still leaving this up because it might be useful to somebody.